# Getting only one item or the first item of the table in Dynamo DB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way that I query only the first item appearing in the table in Dynamo DB? Like for instance if I have 20k records. I don't want to get all the 20k first, and then get the first. I want it to query only the first one found in the table without passing a primary key or a sort key.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Scan the table or index setting the `Limit` parameter to 1. If there is **no filter expression** this will return the "first" item (of course if the table or index has no records nothing will be returned).

From the DynamoDB [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.Limit):

> For example, suppose that you Scan a table with a Limit value of 6 and without a filter expression. The Scan result contains the first six items from the table.

> Now suppose that you add a filter expression to the Scan. In this case, DynamoDB applies the filter expression to the six items that were returned, discarding those that do not match. The final Scan result contains six items or fewer, depending on the number of items that were filtered.

Note that that the records in a table/index are ordered by hashed value of the partition key. AWS does not disclose the hash algorithm used by DynamoDB, so while the order is deterministic (i.e. you get the records in the same order every time you scan) there isn't a good way to set the order of these records).

Comment: I've found the answer through this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ScanJavaDocumentAPI.html. Thanks for the guide

Comment: This is wrong, `Limit` limits the number of rows evaluated, not the number of rows returned.

Comment: Very misleading, Limit is not an actual limit of returned rows.

Comment: Limit does limit the number of returned rows. It just does this by limiting the number of evaluated rows. You can hardly expect that setting a Limit would guarantee that a certain number of rows would always be returned (consider the case of an an empty table or index).

Answer (score 0):

Query the table and get only the first result and only 1 object.

```
const params = {
        TableName: "Logins",
        Limit : 1
    },
    docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(),

    returnObj = {};
    docClient.scan(params, function(err, data){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
          console.log(data)
        }
```